# Why FlowDefinition Not Deploying via ANT Migration Tool

Tags: metadata-api, visual-workflow, migration-tool

Deploying Flows between 2 orgs. The Flows are deploying but not being made active. When I tried just using FlowDefinition in my package.xml Deployment Status showed 0/0 Deploy Components. Tried API 37.0-39.0

I have the flow, Schedule.flow-357 in destination org. Flow is inactive. Also tried deploying both at same time, still FlowDefinition didn't work. Tried deploy to 2 different orgs, same issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FlowDefinition xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <activeVersionNumber>357</activeVersionNumber>
    <description>Master Schedule Flow.</description>
    <masterLabel>Schedule Flow</masterLabel>
</FlowDefinition>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
            <types>
            <members>*</members>
            <name>Flow</name>
        </types>
        <types>
            <members>*</members>
            <name>FlowDefinition</name>
        </types>
<version>38.0</version>
</Package>
```